# Matplotlib not working for LInux. Cannot load backend 'TkAgg'

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

Trying to use Matplotlib on Linux, but I keep getting this error:

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

I am using a virtual environment on OS: Linux 18.04 LTS. Python version: 3.6

I have tried many solutions other posts have suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev libpng-dev libffi-dev dvipng texlive-latex-base
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip --no-cache-dir install matplotlib
```

I have tried fiddling with the python script where matplotlib is used:

```
#TOP OF FILE
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') # or 'TkAgg', or removing the line altogether
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

Running python to see what backend is being used:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()   # -> 'agg'
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: You are running these scripts from the command line and not from some IDE/notebook that may have already attempted to load matplotlib?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue using iPython on macOS getting the error message

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

> ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk'
>   interactive framework, as 'macosx' is currently running

I was able to show my plots using

```
matplotlib.use('WebAgg') # shows in the browser
```

or

```
matplotlib.use('MacOSX') # shows on the desktop
```

To get list of all available backends I typed:

```
matplotlib.use('?')
...
```

> ValueError: Unrecognized backend string '?': valid strings are 
>   ['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'Qt4Agg', 'Qt4Cairo',
>   'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg',
>   'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']

See also [What is a backend?](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

Answer (score -1):

Download and use MobaXterm. This solved the same issue for me.